# host termination not working in ambassador ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ambassador

I got an issue with host termination, while using ambassador as ingress in my bare-metal kubernetes cluster. Actually I got an DNS record for
`*.k8s.mydomain.com` -> `10.16.0.99` (sole node in my cluster). While applying a mapping like

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Mapping
metadata:    
  name: quote-backend
  namespace: ambassador
spec:
  prefix: /
  service: quote
  ambassador_id: externalid
  host: quote.k8s.mydomain.com
```

and opening `https://quote.k8s.mydomain.com` in the browser I'm thrown to the edge-control login page. Any hints what might go wrong in here?

"quote" pod is running in

```
quote-78986d7d8f-cgm8v              1/1     Running   0          11d   172.31.223.222   10.16.0.99   <none>
```

Quote pod is running, as described in the setup guide. Service for quote is running in namespace "ambassador" with name "quote" and is defined as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: quote
  namespace: ambassador
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
selector:
  app: quote
```